# What is the equivalent of MSSQL to Open Source

Tags: database

I want the equivalent of MSSQL to opensource DB?

Comment: installable on windows systems

Comment: MySQL and Postgres both have Windows installers.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of opensource rdbms. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/) are among the more common ones.

Comment: Regarding differences between MySQL and MSSQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616/differences-between-mysql-and-ms-sql.  Also, no FULL OUTER JOIN (you have to do UNIONS with LEFT/RIGHT JOIN) + no recursive queries (you have to make a stored proc w/ temporary table).  MSSQL can do this easily.  Plus, PHPmyAdmin or whatever is no SQL Server Mgmt Studio.  MySQL is ok, though.  Just like Open Office is ok, just don't expect MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually require open source, or are you just trying to keep costs down?

If open source, I would suggest [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), since I believe it to be more robust than MySQL. If you are looking for lower cost alternatives to SQL Server, you might want to look at [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html), or [DB2 Express-C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/).

Comment: Since PostgreSQL uses BSD-style licensing, it tends to be a more attractive choice in business environments.

Answer (score 0):

David mentioned the main big ones out there which are deployed in a ton of environments. If this is for personal use, on a small project, you may find [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) more suitable. I wouldn't consider it a fully-fledged replacement, but it works well for personal projects. SQLite is the [most widely deployed](http://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html) SQL database engine overall as it is used in software like Skype, Firefox and Solaris 10.

Comment: Its not for personal project, but for an accounting package